# Preserve order in geom_rect()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dilemma. In my excel csv file, I have a list of sequences in a certain order and I have written a code to display the sequences hoping that the order is preserved. However, as you see below, the order is not preserved.

[image]

But as you can see here, the sequences are arranged based on their "type". Is there a way to change that and have them plotted in the same order as in the data file?

[image]

My code is:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_rect(data = data, 
              mapping = aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 1, xmin = Start, xmax = End, fill = Type)) + 
    facet_grid(Seqname ~ .) + 
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

Here I am providing a sample of the data using dput as well.

```
> dput(head(data,20))
structure(list(Seqname = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 64L, 
60L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 65L, 65L, 71L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 62L, 
62L), .Label = c("deletionandhypermutR0080_HIV_AG8_CONTIG_1202_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0102_HIV_AA6_CONTIG_3034_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0105_HIV_AA9_CONTIG_1201_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0116_HIV_AB8_CONTIG_4375_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0130_HIV_AC10_CONTIG_1202_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0231_HIV_BD4_CONTIG_1202_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0233_HIV_BD6_CONTIG_1202_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0234_HIV_BD7_CONTIG_1202_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0235_HIV_BD8_CONTIG_1202_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0236_HIV_BD9_CONTIG_1202_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0239_HIV_BD12_CONTIG_1202_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0240_HIV_BE1_CONTIG_1151_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0242_HIV_BE3_CONTIG_1202_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0244_HIV_BE5_CONTIG_1202_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0248_HIV_BE9_CONTIG_1956_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0251_HIV_BE12_CONTIG_1202_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0252_HIV_BF1_CONTIG_1202_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0253_HIV_BF2_CONTIG_1202_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0254_HIV_BF3_CONTIG_1202_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0257_HIV_BF6_CONTIG_1202_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0258_HIV_BF7_CONTIG_1202_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0265_HIV_BG2_CONTIG_1202_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0268_HIV_BG5_CONTIG_1201_p1", 
"deletionandhypermutR0273_HIV_BG10_CONTIG_1201_p1", "deletionandhypermutR0276_HIV_BH1_CONTIG_1202_p1", 
"deletionandinversionB6_Cp35pt5_1sampleB8_CB6_CONTIG_1103_p1", 
"deletionandinversionB8_Cp35pt5_1sampleC5_CB8_CONTIG_6627_p1", 
"deletionandinversionR0079_HIV_AG7_CONTIG_1117_p1", "deletionandinversionR0104_HIV_AA8_CONTIG_1155_p1", 
"deletionandinversionR0175_HIV_AG7_CONTIG_1888_p1", "deletionandinversionR0177_HIV_AG9_CONTIG_1103_p1", 
"deletionandinversionR0232_HIV_BD5_CONTIG_3686_p1", "deletionandinversionR0238_HIV_BD11_CONTIG_3686_p1", 
"deletionandinversionR0245_HIV_BE6_CONTIG_1103_p1", "deletionandinversionR0255_HIV_BF4_CONTIG_1124_p1", 
"deletionandinversionR0259_HIV_BF8_CONTIG_1103_p1", "deletionandinversionR0261_HIV_BF10_CONTIG_1103_p1", 
"deletionandinversionR0262_HIV_BF11_CONTIG_3686_p1", "deletionandinversionR0263_HIV_BF12_CONTIG_1124_p1", 
"deletionandinversionR0270_HIV_BG7_CONTIG_1103_p1", "HypermutB10_Cp35pt5_1sampleC8_CB10_CONTIG_9019_p1", 
"HypermutB12_Cp35pt5_1sampleE2_CB12_CONTIG_9019_p1", "HypermutB5_Cp35pt5_1sampleA10_CB5_CONTIG_9019_p1", 
"HypermutB7_Cp35pt5_1sampleC2_AE11_CONTIG_9004_p1", "HypermutC3_Cp35pt5_1sampleF5_CC3_CONTIG_9010_p1", 
"HypermutR0126_HIV_AC6_CONTIG_9019_p1", "HypermutR0135_HIV_AD3_CONTIG_9019_p1", 
"HypermutR0201_HIV_BA10_CONTIG_9020_p1", "IntactR0176_HIV_AG8_CONTIG_9004_p1", 
"LargedeletionB11_Cp35pt5_1sampleC9_CB11_CONTIG_4324_p1", "LargedeletionB9_Cp35pt5_1sampleC6_CB9_CONTIG_7287_p1", 
"LargedeletionC4_Cp35pt5_1sampleG8_CC4_CONTIG_277_p1", "LargedeletionF3_Cp34pt5_1sampleB4_CF3_CONTIG_1042_p1", 
"LargedeletionR0099_HIV_AA3_CONTIG_775_p1", "LargedeletionR0100_HIV_AA4_CONTIG_5077_p1", 
"LargedeletionR0101_HIV_AA5_CONTIG_2639_p1", "LargedeletionR0103_HIV_AA7_CONTIG_6233_p1", 
"LargedeletionR0106_HIV_AA10_CONTIG_5882_p1", "LargedeletionR0127_HIV_AC7_CONTIG_6333_p1", 
"LargedeletionR0129_HIV_AC9_CONTIG_888_p1", "LargedeletionR0241_HIV_BE2_CONTIG_1086_p1", 
"LargedeletionR0243_HIV_BE4_CONTIG_1371_p1", "LargedeletionR0246_HIV_BE7_CONTIG_2881_p1", 
"LargedeletionR0247_HIV_BE8_CONTIG_794_p1", "LargedeletionR0256_HIV_BF5_CONTIG_1153_p1", 
"LargedeletionR0260_HIV_BF9_CONTIG_3119_p1", "LargedeletionR0266_HIV_BG3_CONTIG_437_p1", 
"LargedeletionR0267_HIV_BG4_CONTIG_351_p1", "LargedeletionR0269_HIV_BG6_CONTIG_978_p1", 
"LargedeletionR0271_HIV_BG8_CONTIG_1486_p1", "LargedeletionR0272_HIV_BG9_CONTIG_303_p1", 
"LargedeletionR0274_HIV_BG11_CONTIG_2748_p1", "LargedeletionR0275_HIV_BG12_CONTIG_350_p1"
), class = "factor"), Start = c(638L, 1638L, 2638L, 3638L, 4638L, 
8845L, 637L, 638L, 1638L, 2638L, 3638L, 4638L, 637L, 9483L, 9316L, 
637L, 1637L, 2637L, 637L, 1637L), End = c(1637L, 2637L, 3637L, 
4637L, 5005L, 9633L, 1542L, 1637L, 2637L, 3637L, 4637L, 4964L, 
1636L, 9633L, 9633L, 1636L, 2636L, 3511L, 1636L, 2000L), Type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Deletion and hypermut", "Deletion and inversion", 
"Hypermut", "Intact", "Large deletion"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Seqname", 
"Start", "End", "Type"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply! I just tried it out but am unsure where about in the code to insert it.

Comment: `data<-read.csv("file.csv")`
`fct_inorder(data)`
`Error: f must be a factor (or character vector).`

Comment: If you could provide a sample of the data with `dput` it would be much easier to provide insights.

Comment: Thanks @missuse, I edited my question and added some sample data using `dput`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I stated in the comment, ggplot treats character columns as factors and sorts their levels alphabetically. The change the order of plotting one must change the order of levels of the corresponding factors. In this case `Seqname`. There are several ways this can be accomplished. Probably the easiest is using `forcats::fct_inorder` which is made for this kind of task.

Here is an approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-  droplevels.data.frame(df) #first to remove all the empty levels from your example

df %>%
  mutate(Seqname = forcats::fct_inorder(Seqname)) %>%
  ggplot()+ 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 1, xmin = Start, xmax = End, fill = Type)) + 
  facet_grid(Seqname ~ .) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle=0))
```

[image]

without the level reorder the plot looks like this:

[image]

By changing the order of levels of Type for instance you can change the legend order:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Seqname = forcats::fct_inorder(Seqname),
         Type = relevel(Type, ref = "Large deletion")) %>%
  ggplot()+ 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = 1, xmin = Start, xmax = End, fill = Type)) + 
  facet_grid(Seqname ~ .) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle=0))
```

[image]

I added an additional rotation of the facet text.

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU! I was loading the library now to play with it but was trying to figure out what "%>%" means as it is not going through when I copy and paste it. Is it another form of -> ?
 Your answer is really comprehensive. You truly went above and beyond.

Comment: @Radwa Sharaf  `%>%` is called a `pipe` it provides a means to write code from left to right instead of from the inside out (or to make a bunch of intermediary objects in the environment). Although the pipe can be used with base R its popularity came with dplyr/tidyverse. To use it you need to load `tidyverse`.

Comment: Got it, it is a pipe. This worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch!